# десериалиазация Jackson null значения в empty collection

Tags: java, json, null, jackson

Имеется json строка для представляющая какой то POJO класс , в котором есть коллекции и Map , в json проставленны значения null :

```
{ 
list:null,
map:null
}
```

POJO.java

```
@Data
public class POJO {
private List<Object> list = new ArrayList();
private Map<String,Object> = new HashMap();
}
```

как сделать чтобы при десериализации null значения десериализовывалсь в пустые коллекции?? Желательно не через изменение POJO так их много и менять каждую не желательно, а через конфиг ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 1):

```
mapper.setDefaultSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
```

Comment: Спасибо , хороший совет по идеи должно работать , но может подскажете что-то ещё т.к. к сожалению используется версия jackson 2.8.7

Comment: Тогда только явно определять в pojo сеттер, игнорирующий null.